# Use after effects to create a blinking courser typewriter effect with highlight effect at the same time

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I am trying to replicate the typing animation from - https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9UBf.jpg - in after effects.

For the text I'm using:

```
`var sign = "|"; // change the blinking sign to "▌"or "_"
var blinkInterval = 15; // edit the blinking interval in frames
// slider with text length
var i = effect("Text")("ADBE Slider Control-0001"); 
// checkbox to turn the cursor on and off 
var on = effect("On/Off")("ADBE Checkbox Control-0001"); 

var frames = timeToFrames(time);

var check = frames / blinkInterval;

if (on == 1) {
  if (i.valueAtTime(time + thisComp.frameDuration) > i) {  
    end = sign;
  } else {
    if (Math.floor(check) % 2 == 0) { 
      end = sign;
    } else {
      end = " ";
    }
  }
} else {
  end = " ";
}

text.sourceText.substr(0,parseInt(i)) + end; `
```

Which works but then I have to manually add the white revealing lines behind the text. The example I'm trying to emulate seems to have this connected to the typewriter function somehow. This will also be of benefit as I won't have to modify many trim paths if I change the length of the text at any time.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

See above for the code I tried.

Comment: Will your text be multi-line (wrapped inside a fixed with container), like in the linked clip? If not, you could add a solid, anchor it and the text layer the same anchor coordinates. Then, you would expand / contract the solid based on whether there's more or less text. If you're having multiple lines of text / pressing Enter, then this wouldn't work for you out of the box - you'd need to repeat this for every line of text.

Comment: I will have multiple lines but this will still be quicker than what I have, thank you I will give this a go for now.